# I want to Increase the width of my kitchen by 2 feet, Is it possible?

Tags: extension

My house is under construction and have just completed concreting the ground floor ceiling and now under curing. First floor work will start after 15 days.
The kitchen size is 9ft x 11ft and would like to increase the size by 2ft towards utility which is now measuring 6ft x 11 ft.
Do I need to make a new foundation next the old foundation wall to extend the kitchen wall ? 
Please advice

Thanks
Mathew

Comment: This is a question for your engineer/architect, not a bunch of dolts on the internet. The engineer/architect can look at the building plans, we cannot.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough info to really answer, but generally as long as your willing to loose the two feet somewhere else then yes you can extend the kitchen.

A lot depends on the type of construction and other factors, your contractor/builder will know best. Again, generally, as long as your staying inside the exterior walls, just about anything can be done.

Other considerations exist however. In some construction types plumbing is laid before the concrete is poured. In those cases it may be expensive to move something like the sink, at the same time, it may cost next to nothing to move an empty wall over 2 feet into what was going to be a closet or something.

There are possibilities, but it will depend on your floor plan, your builder, your construction type, and other factors. Your builder is the best to ask about this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends," and the architect or a local engineer who can look at the plans and the foundation is the right person to ask.

For instance, if the wall in question is not load bearing, then it probably won't matter (unless there is some engineered shear component to the wall, in which case it *might* matter).

If it *is* load bearing, maybe you can cantilever the joists out over the footing, maybe that would require bigger joists, or maybe you have to pour a new footing in the new location. The architect/engineer could do the proper calculations and tell you what you need to do.